# regexp pattern to match alphanumeric strings without initial spaces

Tags: regex, space

i have input pattern setted like this: `pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+"`

When i type a space in the input, it returns me a error message ( which is good ).

But, when i type mi full name, for e.g. `Jhonatan Sandoval`, it does too.

How can i sett the **pattern only with no spaces** before the name?

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with HTML5, and even less with design patterns.

Comment: What about input `" Jhonatan"` - should that be an error or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will work as you expect:

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"
```